# How to add and update table row in same method using Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I need to insert data and update a table row in one method in My Controller using Laravel 5.2. My table name is "permission". Here is My method:

```
public function addPermission(Request $request, $id,  Permission $permission)
{
    if ($permission = Permission::findOrFail($id));{
     $this->validate($request, [
        'status'   => 'required'


    ]);

    $permission = new Permission;

    $permission->status = $request->input('status');
    $permission->project_id       = $id;

    $permission->collaborator_id =  $request->input('cid');

    $values = $request->all();
    $permission->fill($values)->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('info','Permission has been updated to your Collaborator successfully');
    }
    else  {

     $this->validate($request, [
        'status'   => 'required'


    ]);

    $permission = new Permission;

    $permission->status = $request->input('status');
    $permission->project_id       = $id;

    $permission->collaborator_id =  $request->input('cid');
    $permission->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with('info','Permission has been added to your Collaborator successfully');

   }  
}
```

I get the following error

> syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if ($permission = Permission::findOrFail($id));{   you've got ';' between if and opening bracket.

Comment: It's just a syntax error which should be easily caught by you even before running the code, provided you're using a smart IDE, such as PhpStorm or NetBeans (you really should be).

Answer (score 1):

For syntax Erorr

```
if ($permission = Permission::findOrFail($id)); { ......
```

Just remove ";"

```
if ($permission = Permission::findOrFail($id)) { .....
```